# Comparison of data in Access

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I have written some pretty lengthy VBA code in excel for the comparison of 2 worksheets. My code does the following:

- Lets you import 2 sheets for comparison
- arranges the columns
- removes departments which require different comparisons into a new worksheet
- In sheet 1 checks if the id's appear more than once then checks, which row of data to use for comparison based on the latest update, and deletes the old rows
- compares the sheets based on the header and then the cell contents as header names are different, for different values it then highlights them red
- finally giving me a breakdown per column per department of differences and any id's that are missing

I have now found that my data set is becoming to big and looking to use MS Access, is it possible to copy my VBA code over to access? What do you guys suggest for this?

Any advice would be helpful.

Comment: My thoughts are that you will be able to use your old code as a reference.  But you will need to re-write it almost entirely.  Work on that and as you run into issues, just post your specific issues here and we will help.

Answer (score 0):

From the nature of your question it sounds like you may not have used a database before.  If you were using access, you would need to totally re-write the code using SQL statements.  eg An Aggregating  SQL SELECT statement to find the most recently updated update and ignore the rest.

You can use conditional formatting in an access form, but it's no better than using it in excel.  How many rows does your data have? Will it fit in an excel sheet?

You might use access to pre-process the data to remove the unwanted rows that you use in excel.  OR use power query or sql directly from excel to remove them.

You have a way to go.

Harvy